# Unable to generate a URL for "page_slug", after creating a user

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I have a strange problem. I installed and configured SonataUserBundle to work with FosUserBundle and SonataAdminBundle. The installed went without any problems and everything seems to be working perfectly, except when I create another user via sonataUserBundle web page. Once I create the user (and it is created when I look in the database), I cannot see the users list anymore. When I click to return to the users list, I get the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "page_slug" as such route does not exist.") in "SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig".
```

If I delete the user from the database, to only have one user, then I can access the users list.

I have absolutely no clue on how to get further on how to resolve this issue...

Edit 1:

I found out, thanks to Marko Jurinčič that I have these lines in my config

```
sonata_user:

    impersonating:
        route:                page_slug
        parameters:           { path: / }
```

However, this doesn't look like a route and effectively, there are no routes named page_slug whatsoever. Is it supposed to have a route name "page_slug" ?

Comment: Are you logged with the new user? What about permissions?

Comment: No, I mean when I create a user in the admin page (with my admin user), I cannot access the users list anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw on an approach on a website (http://www.laurent-masforne.com/memo/surcharger-sonatauserbundle-notamment-useradmin/) and commenting those lines :

```
/*if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH')) {
            $listMapper
                ->add('impersonating', 'string', array('template' => 'SonataUserBundle:Admin:Field/impersonating.html.twig'))
            ;
        }*/
```

in `vendor\sonata-project\user-bundle\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\ApplicationUserAdmin`

resolved the issue. However, I don't know the impacts of doing such a thing...

Answer (score 6):

I am having the same problem. What I did was to search for page_slug in my project and I found that page_slug is used in my config.yml under sonata_user

```
impersonating:
  route: page_slug
  parameters: { path: / }
```

I still have to take a look to see if this affects something else (I am kind of new to Symfony, so I am not 100% sure that this is not used somewhere else :) )

Commenting (or just removing) this fixed my issue and now I can see the listing of users in the admin dahsboard.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:
I found the answer. In this link is explained the meaning of impersonating:
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/174

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, it is already not commented. I have this in my config :     

impersonating:
        route:                page_slug
        parameters:           { path: / }

But it is still saying that I don't have the route name page_slug.

Comment: My bad, you have to comment it or just remove it.

Answer (score 5):

### Remove broken config

In your case if you will not use impersonating you should just delete lines from config:

```
impersonating:
  route:                page_slug
  parameters:           { path: / }
```

### Configure impersonating

(May this be found by google wanderers)

Otherwise you need to configure impersonating:
1. User needs to have role `ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH`. I configured admin to have this role:

```
# app/config/security.yml  
security:  
  role_hierarchy:  
    ROLE_ADMIN:  [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

2. Allow user switching in firewall:

```
# app/config/security.yml      
firewalls:
  main:
    switch_user: true
```

3. (If you want a link in Sonata Admin user list) Setup SonataUserBundle - replace `my_home_route` with the route name to be opened after clicking link to switch user:

```
# app/config/config.yml
sonata_user:
  impersonating:
    route:  my_home_route
```

### Manual user switching

To manually switch user add string to url end: `?_switch_user=username`. Change `username` to real username.

Comment: That's so interesting ! If I get that right, impersonating means acting as another role. Therefore, I'm assuming that a ROLE_ADMIN could be impersonating a ROLE_USER, since ROLE_USER has less privileges than ROLE_ADMIN but this wouldn't work the other way around ?

Comment: Impersonating means acting as another _user_. You will get all privileges from user you impersonate.

Comment: I mean I hope a user with less privileges (ROLE_USER) cannot impersonate one with higher privileges (ROLE_ADMIN)

Comment: Actually ROLE_USER **can** impersonate ROLE_ADMIN. Just tried it. Added ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH to ROLE_USER, logged in with not privileged user, impersonated admin, got all privileges and even deleted the same user I initially logged in with :D